# How to send a USSD message to a specific user without using any server?

Tags: java, android, ussd

I'm trying to build an android app that would have the basic functionality of sending a short text Message via USSD to a specific mobile number.
is that possible in any way without establishing a web server and only by creating a peer to peer session between two mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

USSD is not IP, web, or whatever technology around internet. USSD works on mobile networks and messages are transported on the signaling network. In other words, whenever you type `#xyz#` on your mobile phone, as a call or in an app you've developped, the message is sent to your mobile telco operator on a USSD Gateway, a platform hosted by the telco. That gateway ***may*** use HTTP(S) to have the request processed and retrieve the menus to be sent back to the user, that HTTP server ***may*** be located on the internet, but this is absolutely not mandatory and most of the time it's not the case.

If you want to write a messaging app using USSD, you have to have an agreement with a mobile telco and your app as likely to only work on his network